# Add column to dataFrame with new data?

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas I have created a dataframe from importing from CSV.

```
data = pd.read_csv('pathToCSV', index_col=[0],usecols=[0,2,3],names=['Date','High','Low'])
```

Output looks like this-

```
2009.09.18  112  111
2009.09.19  114  222
```

Now what if I want to calculate an average of the two columns, row by row, and then add the value as a new column?
What I did was

```
average = (data[1]+data[2])/2
```

Then

```
data.join(average)
```

But I get an error! I am doing this correct?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5325, in _join_compat
    raise ValueError('Other Series must have a name')
ValueError: Other Series must have a name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just looking for the `mean` function, which you want to apply row-wise (`axis = 1`) to the columns `High` and `Low`:

```
# starting with frame:
>>> data
         Date  High  Low
0  2009.09.18   112  111
1  2009.09.19   114  222

# Use:
data['row_average'] = data[['High','Low']].mean(axis=1)

# and you end up with the frame:
>>> data
         Date  High  Low  row_average
0  2009.09.18   112  111        111.5
1  2009.09.19   114  222        168.0
```

Comment: And thanks for the explanation of "row-wise (axis = 1)" much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

While sacul is absolutely correct, you may consider the following solution as well.

```
def avg(x,y):
    return (x+y)/2
df['row_avg'] = df[['High','Low']].apply(lambda x:avg(*x),axis=1)
```

The advantage of this approach is you can define any function and then apply to `DataFrame` rows.